# Sitemap in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sitemap

In _app_bin\layouts.sitemap of the sharepoint project. I have added a new sitemap node for a page inorder to define its own top link navigation in sharepoint. When i browse through that page. It is also showing the Sitename/Pagename prepended with the sitemapnode title.
My wish is to not to have the page name which was prepended with the sitemapnode title.
My doubt is that how the SiteName/Pagename is coming prepended with the Site navigation?.